# Mapstruct A single object multiple attribute of the source is mapped to an attribute of the target

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have three objects: **AttendanceClickDTO**, **AttendanceClick**, **AttendanceTime**.

```java
@Data
public class AttendanceClickDTO {

    private LocalDate attendanceDate;
    private LocalDateTime clickTime;

}
```

```java
@Data
public class AttendanceClick {

    private AttendanceTime attendanceTime;

}
```

```java
@Getter
public class AttendanceTime {

    private final LocalDate attendanceDate;
    private final LocalDateTime clickTime;

    @Default
    public AttendanceTime(LocalDate attendanceDate, LocalDateTime clickTime) {
        this.attendanceDate = attendanceDate;
        this.clickTime = clickTime;
    }
|
```

I want :

1. **AttendanceClickDTO** -> **AttendanceClick**
2. (**AttendanceClickDTO.attendanceDate** + **AttendanceClickDTO.clickTime**) -> **AttendanceClick.attendanceTime**

So I create a **AppAttendanceConverter**.

```java
@Mapper(
        componentModel = "spring",
        uses = {CommonConverter.class}
)
public interface AppAttendanceConverter {
//    @Mapping(target = "attendanceTime.attendanceDate", source = "attendanceClickDTO.attendanceDate")
//    @Mapping(target = "attendanceTime.clickTime", source = "attendanceClickDTO.clickTime")
    AttendanceClick toAttendanceClick(AttendanceClickDTO attendanceClickDTO, StaffInfo staffInfo, DepartmentInfo departmentInfo);

    default AttendanceTime toAttendanceTime(LocalDate attendanceDate, LocalDateTime clickTime) {
        return new AttendanceTime( attendanceDate, clickTime );
    }
}
```

I want mapstruct aotumatic invoke **toAttendanceTime** method, Not use

> @Mapping(target = "attendanceTime.attendanceDate", source =
> "attendanceClickDTO.attendanceDate")
> @Mapping(target = "attendanceTime.clickTime", source = "attendanceClickDTO.clickTime")

So what should I do?
Please.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Mapping(target = "attendanceTime", qualifiedByName = "toAttendanceTime")
AttendanceClick toAttendanceClick(AttendanceClickDTO attendanceClickDTO, StaffInfo staffInfo, DepartmentInfo departmentInfo);

@Named("toAttendanceTime") 
default AttendanceTime toAttendanceTime(AttendanceClickDTO attendanceClickDTO) { 
    return new AttendanceTime( attendanceClickDTO.getAttendanceDate(), attendanceClickDTO.getClickTime() );
}
```